# How to display the text with the value at the same time from my dropdownlist select option tag?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to display these centimeters in my dropdownlist along with the price which was put on my value

```
<label>Select Height</label>
                  
                  <select name="psheight" id="psheight" style="width:50%;" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" onchange="changeddl(this)"  >
                  <?php
                    $conn = $pdo->open();

                    try{
                      $now = date('Y-m-d');
                      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customize_ps_height");
                      $stmt->execute();
                      foreach($stmt as $row){
                          
                      ?>
                      
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['price'];?> <?php echo $row['height'];?>"><?php echo $row['height']; ?></option>
                        
                      <?php
                        
                     
                      }
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e){
                      echo $e->getMessage();
                    }

                    $pdo->close();
                  ?>
                </select>
                  <div class="divheight" class="height-style"></div>
                <div class="divprice" class="price-style"></div>
```

```
<script>
  function changeddl($this){
    
$($this).next('.divheight').text($this.value>0?("Height: " + $this.value + " ₱"):"");
   $($this).next('.divprice').text($this.value>0?("Price: " + $this.value + " ₱"):"");

   
};
</script>
```

[heres my output but i wanted also to display the centimeter which is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3YE.png)

Comment: You _combined_ price and height with a space character as separator in your option value - so you will need to split them again, if you want separate access to both values.

Comment: But instead of sticking them both into the value attribute to begin with, it might make more sense to put one of them into a custom data attribute instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Please don't mix template and backend code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this.value is contain price value. You should use $this.text, because it is height value. You should change the js function as below

```
if($this.value>0){ 
$('.divHeight').text('Height: '+$('#psheight option:selected').text());
$('.divPrice').text("Price: " + $this.value);
}
```